# Convert c++ function from recursive to iterations with stack

Tags: c++, function, recursion, stack, iteration

I'm trying to convert this function from recursive to iterations with stack but I can't figure out how and I keep failing

```c
int F(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    int a = n + F(n - 1);
    cout << a << endl;
    int b = n * F(n / 2);
    int c = n - 2 - (a + b) % 2;
    int d = F(c);
    return a + b + d;
}
```

I tried to debug the code and break it down but luck was not on my side

edit:
these are the requirements

- You are not allowed to use any built-in functions except those from: `<cstdlib>`, `<cstdio>`, `<cstring>`, `<iostream>` and `<stack>`.
- You are not allowed to use `string`, `vector`, or anything from STL libraries except `stack`.

Moreover, I attempted to make multiple stack for each variable to store the results then substitute the answer but am still working on it.

Comment: please also show your attempt, incude the code with iterations and the stack in the question

Comment: btw I also dont see how this can be solved (easily) with a stack. Why do you think you should use a stack?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Probably just because every recursion can be translated into iteration with a stack (simulating the call stack). So this is the generic approach.

Comment: Luck is a poor advocate when doing debugging... you should not rely on it ;) Anyway, do you have problems understanding the code you are showing or the one you wrote in you attempts? In the first case you should tell us what exactly your did not understand, in the second case you should include your attempt in the question.

Comment: @JakobStark am not having difficulty in understanding the code, I just can't figure out how to convert this code

Comment: @mick instead of using `std::vector` as suggested in the answers below, you could use a raw array of `int` as pseudo stack and access not only the top element but also the top-1 element etc. This may be considered "cheating", but the requirements you mentioned in the edit, doesn't _require_ the usage of `std::stack`, it only _allows_ it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the single parts of the recursion:

We have `f(n-1)`, `f(n/2)` and `f(n-2-[0 or 1]`, no matter how big `a` or `b` might ever get. All these recursive calls fall back to a lower value.

First few values:

```
f(n) = 1; // n <= 1
f(2) = (2 + f(1)) + (2 * f(1)) + f(-1) // (c = 2 - 2 - 5 % 2)
     = 6
f(3) = (3 + f(2)) + (3 * f(1)) + f(1) // (c = 3 - 2 - 12 % 2)
     = 13
f(4) = (4 + f(3)) + (4 * f(2)) + f(1)  // (c = 4 - 2 - 41 % 2)
     = 42
f(5) = (5 + f(4)) + (5 * f(2)) + f(2)  // (c = 5 - 2 - 77 % 2)
     = 83
```

Obviously we can calculate a new value based on old ones – and if we calculate these first, we can simply look them up – apart from `n == 2` where we'd get a negative lookup index. So we might initialise a `std::vector` with `f(0)`, `f(1)` and `f(2)` (i.e. 1, 1, 6) and then iterate from `3` onwards until `n` calculating new values based upon the lookups of old ones:

```
    if n <= 1:
        return 1;
    std::vector v({1, 1, 6});
    if n >= v.size():
        v.reserve(n + 1); // avoid unnecessary re-allocations
        iterate i from v.size() up to n inclusive:
            v.push_back(calculate, instead recursive calls look up in vector!);
    return v[n];
```

Optimisation opportunity: If you retain results from previous calculations you don't need to re-calculate the values again and again (for the price of constantly instead of temporarily consuming quite a bit of memory!); all you have to do for is making the vector *`static`*:

```
   static std::vector v({1, 1, 6});
// ^^^^^^
```

*Edit – according to the edits of the question (referring to version 4):*

As you are not allowed to use `std::vector` as proposed above instead allocate an array:

```
auto v = new unsigned int[std::max(3, n + 1)] { 1, 1, 6};
// I personally prefer unsigned int as negative values aren't possible anyway...

// calculate as with the vector

auto result = v[n];
delete[] v;
return result;
```

Keeping old values for future calls still is possible, but more complicated; you need to remember how large your array is and if `n` is greater than the size re-allocate a new array, copy values from old one to and delete the latter.

This approach keeps the requirements of the task as using `std::stack` is not explicitly requested... If that gets enforced then the algorithm won't change – solely the lookup gets pretty ugly; you need in addition to your main stack a temporary one to be able to backup the elements on top of those you want to lookup up:

```
// lookup the three values in DESCENDING order, each one
// as follows:
while(stack.size() > lookupIndex)
{
    backup.push(stack.top());
    stack.pop();
}
// now top elements have been moved away from main stack and
// backed up; the element to be looked up is moved, too;
// for illustration: consider lookupIndex == 0; what would be
// the main stack's size after popping the surplus elements???
lookupValue = backup().top();

// now as you have looked up all three values move the elements
// in the backup stack back to the main stack:
while(!backup.empty()) { /* analogously to above */ }
```

You can spare moving back if you are calculating the final value for `n`  – unless you retain the main stack for future calls analogously to the static vector above (make it `static` analogously...).

Final note: I think more than anything else you can learn from this example how much additional effort – in coding and in runtime – you will load upon your shoulders if you chose a bad data structure compared to having chosen a suitable one...

Answer (score 0):

Consider that

```
F(n) = 1 for all n <= 1, especially
F(0) = 1  and  F(1) = 1
```

This is basically all you need to get the solution with a loop:

```
int F2(int n) {
    std::vector<int> F{1,1};
    for (int i=2;i <= n; ++i) {
        int a = i + F[i-1];
        int b = i * F[i/2];
        int x = i-2-(a+b)%2;   // might be negative
        int d = x>0 ? F[x] : 1;        
        F.push_back(a+b+d);
    }
    return F.back();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it is very helpful but is there anyway to implement it using stack not vector ? Thank in advance

Comment: @mick why do you want to use a stack?

Comment: @mick it is possible to implement it using a stack, but it will be considerably more complicated, because you can only access the top element of a stack

Comment: _why do you want to use a stack_: I'd give that 10 upvotes if I could.

Comment: @mick You'd need two stacks for, from main stack you'd pop unwanted elements until being able to peek the one you're interested in (look up largest value first, smallest last!) – and the unwanted elements would need to be stored in a temporary stack so that you can restore the main stack after having done the look-ups. Honestly, would you really want to do that???

Comment: I know that the stack is not the optimum solution but it is required not an option @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @Aconcagua could you illustrate your methodology with a code please. Thanks in advance

Comment: @mick is this homework? There is an issue with this kind of problems: If someone gave you this as homework then they should have taught you the prerequisites. So either you didnt pay attention in class or your teacher does a poor job at explaining. And neither of those two is solved by presenting you a solution. Things get easier if you show your attempt in the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah it is an assignment however the prerequisites are not clear enough and they lack explaining

Comment: @mick consider you have a stack with `n` elements. Do you know how to get the `m`-th (m<n) element from the stack and keep the stack intact? Thats basically what Aconcagua wrote. If you don't know how to do that then you should exercise an example that does only that. Thats one prerequsite

Comment: @mick What is the exact definition of stack you got provided by your teacher? If you have a stack with the additional feature of being able to *lookup* values not on top (while still only pushing and popping from top) then you could use such one... Note, though, that `std::stack` does *not* provide that feature (which is *beyond* the usual/classic definition of 'stack'), so you'd have to write your own lookup-capable stack.

Comment: here is what the teacher said `* You are not allowed to use any built-in functions except: <cstdlib>, <cstdio>, <cstring>, <iostream>, <stack>.
* You are not allowed to use string class, vector, or anything from STL libraries except <stack>.` @Aconcagua

Comment: @mick Might be worth, too, trying to convince your teacher that a stack (classic sense) is *not* a suitable data structure for this problem ;)

Comment: @mick Well – with these requirements actually you are *not* allowed to use `<stack>` either! It is nothing more than a wrapper around another container (by default `std::deque`, but that can be exchanged) – so no other containers, no stack...

Comment: @mick this isnt about knowing the answer, but about writing unecessarily compilcated code, whose only purpose is to learn something while writing it. The exercise is meant for you. I am certain Aconcagua could implement it using a stack, but unless one is forced to one usually chooses the solution and containers that fit the problem, not some other containers that make it unecessarily complicated

Comment: @mick please update the question to include the requirements *and* your attempt for the solution

Comment: @mick What I'd first do is asking your teacher if you are allowed to write your own stack with mentioned lookup feature – or you just *do* so without asking – the requirements imposed by the teacher would be kept that way anyway! Sure, you'd have to care for all the memory management that STL usually does for you, but I'd consider that worth the effort...

Comment: @mick If your teacher *insists* on `std::stack`, then have several while loops: `while(mainStack.size() > lookupIndex) { tmpStack.push(mainStack.peek()); mainStack.pop(); } lookupValue = tmpStack().peek(); /* repeat for the other two values; look them up sorted by descending order! */ while(!tmpStack.empty()) { /* move back to mainStack analogously */ }` – you can spare moving back if you are calculating the final value for `n` (unless you retain the `mainStack` for future calls analogously to the `static` vector in my answer).